# Cant find Packages in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft, minecraft-forge

Recently I have been working on coding Minecraft mods. Yesterday i updated to a 64 bit version of Java, and I began to receive an error that said something of this nature: "Java returned error = 13". I looked around, and discovered that my Eclipse was not 64 bit, so I went to Eclipse, and downloaded the latest 64 bit version. I then replaced my normal eclipse folder with the new one, and it launched fine. However, when I open Eclipse, (I open the exact same workspace as I did before all of this happened), I don't see anything in the Package Explorer view. Nothing at all. Typically it says MDK Example or something like that, and within that are all of my packages, etc.

Here is my question: How can I make it to where I see all of my files in the package explorer like they used to? I am using the same Workspace...

Just a warning: I code a lot, and I believe that now I'm quite skilled at it, however I am not good with computers themselves (hence why I find myself in this predicament). If I need to completely start over, I can, and I can copy over my code. It would be a nuisance but if that is all that is left to do I will do so.

Thank you for reading! Please help if you can :)

Comment: Do you have the 64-bit minecraft?

Comment: this is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/36016014/982161

Answer (score 0):

I remember encountering a similar problem after having switched the location of my workspace.

Try the following: Choose a different location for your workspace and then choose File>Import>General>"Existing Projects into Workspace".